# python tscribe module - KeyError: 'confidence' while exporting redacted content

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-transcribe

I am facing the KeyError: 'confidence' while trying to export the redacted content to Word docx using python tscribe module.

```
File "transcribe_script.py", line 124, in export_files
    tscribe.write(json_file_path, format="docx", save_as= save_as_path)
  File "C:\Users\Shufyan\Anaconda3\envs\upwork\lib\site-packages\tscribe\__init__.py", line 597, in write
    df = decode_transcript(data)
  File "C:\Users\Shufyan\Anaconda3\envs\upwork\lib\site-packages\tscribe\__init__.py", line 167, in decode_transcript
    result = sorted(
  File "C:\Users\Shufyan\Anaconda3\envs\upwork\lib\site-packages\tscribe\__init__.py", line 168, in <lambda>
    word_result[-1]["alternatives"], key=lambda x: x["confidence"]
KeyError: 'confidence'
```

Here's the code:

```
if json_content['results']['transcripts'][0]['transcript'] != "" :
    json_file_path = os.path.join(self.output_path, obj.key)
    save_as_path = os.path.join(self.output_path, obj_name +'.docx')
    tscribe.write(json_file_path, format="docx", save_as= save_as_path)
```

Comment: Hi, please post the code you currently have.

Comment: Hi Peter, the code is fairly simple:
`if json_content['results']['transcripts'][0]['transcript'] != "" :
    json_file_path = os.path.join(self.output_path, obj.key)
    save_as_path = os.path.join(self.output_path, obj_name +'.docx')
    tscribe.write(json_file_path, format="docx", save_as= save_as_path)`
It only fails with the error I mentioned above, when the transcript contain redacted data i.e. [PII] as per AWS. It works fine with the data without redacted value.

Comment: Hi again, please edit your question to include the code.